# Dealing with large numbers on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to use Highstock with numbers that are close to the maximum number (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_max_value.asp) but I get error in highstock: *Error: Invalid value for  attribute d="M 0 -Infinity*.

Here is an example:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            series : [{
                data : [1.7976931348623157e+20, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+30, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+50, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+100, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+120, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+150, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+170, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+200, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+230, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+260, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+300, 
                       1.7976931348623157e+308]
            }]
        });
```

Also you can see it at jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/s6gscza2/2/

I guest the Highstock should show the maximum number or I'm missing some settings.

Answer (score 1):

It means that you have too much digits, because javascrpt function toFixed() is limited to 20 digits.

Comment: I think JavaScript can execute the function with big numbers, for example: `1.7976931348623157e+308.toFixed()`. Anyway, I got to the conclusion that Highstock has problem with numbers bigger than **1.7976931348623157e+119**. So, is this a bug or limitation of the library?

Comment: It's a limiation, at this moment